# How to query for values which have the highest vote count and no flags in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database structure that's sort of like this:

```
nodes
  id

properties
  id
  node_id
  name

assignments
  id
  property_id
  value

votes
  id
  assignment_id

flags
  id
  type
  assignment_id
```

Nodes are objects which have properties. Properties are assigned values, and values are voted on or flagged as incorrect. The question is, what is an appropriate query that will fetch the assignment for each property with the most votes and no flags? I guess I can precompute this value and store it on the properties table like `active_assignment_id`, but I'd still like to know how this query might look, I am not that familiar with SQL but learning it as I go. This is how I am sketching out a query pseudocode, but I imagine it is far from correct.

```
SELECT properties.name,assignments.value FROM properties
  INNER JOIN properties.id = assignments.property_id
  INNER JOIN votes.assignment_id = assignments.id
  INNER JOIN flags.assignment_id = assignments.id
  WHERE COUNT(votes) ...?
  AND COUNT(flags) = 0
```

If there are no votes on the only assignment, the assignment should stll be returned. The vote count is per assignment, and there are a set of assignments for a property. Therefore, the goal is to find the assignment with the highest votes for the property (for each property).

I would like to see how this is done so I can come to grips with more advanced real-world use case of a PostGreSQL query. I have never done anything with this sort of "scoped counting" before in SQL, so not really sure where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below query -

```
SELECT P.name, A.value, V.CNT_VOTES total_votes
  FROM properties P
  INNER JOIN assignments A ON P.id = A.property_id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT assignment_id, COUNT(*) CNT_VOTES
                FROM votes
               GROUP BY assignment_id) V ON V.assignment_id = A.id
  LEFT JOIN flags F ON F.assignment_id = A.id
                   AND F.assignment_id IS NULL
 ORDER BY V.CNT_VOTES DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```